# Postgresql: Disable remote connections for specific user (root)?

Tags: postgresql, access-control

I know that I can disable all remote connections to a Postgresql database by setting the listen_addresses to 'localhost'.

My question is: Can I disable remote access for specific users? I want to disable remote access for all superusers to reduce the attack surface of my database.

Comment: Yes: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html (but the superuser in Postgres is typically named `postgres`, not `root`)

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name - this basically solves this question. If you turn this comment into an answer, I will accept it.